# Data in wpf datagrid (child table) does not match form (parent table)

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, datagrid

I am having problems with parent - child relationships.

I have two tables which have a one to many relationship.  I have a bound combobox on a form of the PARENT ID field and a bound datagrid of the CHILD table.

When I select IDs from the combobox the datagrid data does not change.  It displays all data in its table.

How can I filter/query the data in the datagrid based on the selected I from the combobox?

Comment: If you are facing problems with data, maybe your query is not right.

Comment: provide some code please. It will help us help you!

Comment: I just created a dataset with the two tables.  I then drug the primary key of the parent table to the form as a combobox from the data sources window of visual studio.  In the same manner I drug the entire child table to the form.  It was my belief that this automatically inserts the data binding code.  I made the relationship in MySql Workbench and verified that the relationship exits in the dataset with the VS designer.

Comment: I have edited your question to remove the noise. You have been requested twice to show your code. Please do so.